# File not found while using paramiko.ProxyComand

Tags: python-2.7, proxy, paramiko

I have this part of the code of my file cpe_scan.py:

```
import Crypto
import paramiko
def runSshCmd(hostname, username, password, cmd, timeout=5):
    conf = paramiko.SSHConfig()
    conf.parse(open('/home/me/.ssh/config'))
    host = conf.lookup(hostname)
    print "Object host= ", host
    print "Object host.get= ", host.get('proxycommand')
    proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(host.get('proxycommand'))
    print "Object proxy= ", proxy

    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password,
    allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False, timeout=timeout, sock=proxy)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
    data = stdout.read()
    print data
    client.close()

runSshCmd("1.2.3.4", "user", "passwd", "ls -l")
```

The result is:

```
Object host=  {'hostname': '1.2.3.4', 'proxycommand': 'ssh me@myproxy nc 5.6.7.8 22'}
Object host.get=  ssh me@myproxy nc 5.6.7.8 22
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cpe_scan.py", line 68, in <module>
    runSshCmd("1.2.3.4", "user", "passwd", "ls -l")
File "cpe_scan.py", line 48, in runSshCmd
    proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(host.get('proxycommand'))
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\proxy.py", line 50, in __init__
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato
```

Where "Impossibile trovare il file specificato" is equal to "Can not find the file specified" in english

Why? What file cannot find?

I use python 2.7.6, paramiko 1.12.1, pycrypto 2.6.1 and ecdsa 0.10 and i run on windows xp.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error when using ProxyCommand with ssh. What resolved it was to specify the complete path to both the ssh and nc binaries (`/usr/bin/[ssh|nc]` in my case). Can you try that and see if it fixes the problem in your case? I'm sure you know this, but you can find out the path to the executables using `which ssh` and `which nc`.